# Why doesn't my Express route handler have req.body values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I issue this POST request like so:

```
$ curl -H Content-Type: application/json -X POST -d "{'username':'xyz','password':'xyz'}" http://172.17.0.12:3000/user/add
```

This gets handled by my `node.js` code here:

```
[root@02ffc47edbb8 mynodeapp]# cat routes/user.js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bp = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();
var jsonParser = bp.json();
var urlencodedParser = bp.urlencoded({ extended: false });
//Mongo stuff

mongoose.connect('mongodb://172.17.0.13/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  console.log( 'connected to the mongodb://172.17.0.13/test');
});


var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

var user = mongoose.model( 'User', userSchema );

/*
 * curl -H Content-Type: application/json -X POST -
 * d '{username:xyz,password:xyz}' http://172.17.0.11:3000/user/add
 */


/* add user */
// router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
router.post('/add', jsonParser, function (req, res) {

  // console.log(req);
  console.log(req.body.username);
  if ( !req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
  var newUser = new user({ username: 'fluffy', password: 'a' });
  newUser.save();
  res.send('respond with a resource see http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.post.method');
});

module.exports = router;
```

But the output on my server shows that the `req.body.username` is `undefined`.

```
[root@02ffc47edbb8 mynodeapp]# DEBUG=simplist-app:* npm start

> mynodeapp@0.0.0 start /mynodeapp
> node ./bin/www

connected to the mongodb://172.17.0.13/test
undefined
POST /user/add 200 12.466 ms - 73
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to quote the header information with curl `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: Yes thanks ... I need to do my curl like so : ` curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://172.17.0.12:3000/user/add`

Comment: you don't need to define `-X POST` when including `-d` with curl

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Blakes ... I need to do my curl like so : `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' 172.17.0.12:3000/user/add`